# Launch dialog-based app without leaving full-screen mode

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

The scenario is this:

- I have a desktop app running in full-screen mode (the customer requires the end user to have no access to the OS)
- The desktop app can launch several utilities, two of which are dialog-based apps programmed to be "always on top" of the desktop app
- Problem: when launching the dialog-based apps, the Windows taskbar appears giving the user access to the OS; this will be unacceptable to the customer

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you already running in [kiosk](https://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/) mode?

Comment: No! Kiosk mode is new to me. I'll investigate and post back. Thanks @erapert!!

Comment: Well, that's not going to work. We're using Windows 10 Pro, and our app isn't a "Universal Windows Platform" app, whatever the heck that is! I tried setting up a kiosk account anyway with Groove Music as the app. All I got when I logged in was the Groove Music UI (unresponsive) alternating with a picture every 3 or 4 seconds. It was a pretty picture and all, but utterly useless. Back to square one.

Comment: If you used the system tray to run your app then I think you can hide your main app from the task bar. But i have not played with that for many years. Maybe someone else could.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching the world over for a complex solution, it turned out to be this simple (I used Spy++ to get the window class name):

```
CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(_T("Shell_TrayWnd"), NULL);
pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

Of course, restoring the taskbar is just as easy.
Thanks to all for the feedback!

Dave